# Pandas: using too much memory with conditional rolling count

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do a rolling count of the observations appearing in one column given a fixed window length by group specified in another column. This is better explained with an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['X', 'X' , 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'],
                   'group': ["IT", "IT", "IT", "MV", "MV", "MV", "IT", "MV", "MV", "IT", "IT", "MV"]})

for i in df['B'].unique():
    df.loc[df['B']==i, 'count'] = df.where(df['B'].eq(i)).groupby(df['group'])['B'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3, min_periods=1).count().shift(fill_value=0))
print(df)

    B group  count
0   X    IT    0.0
1   X    IT    1.0
2   Y    IT    0.0
3   X    MV    0.0
4   Y    MV    0.0
5   Y    MV    1.0
6   X    IT    2.0
7   X    MV    1.0
8   Y    MV    2.0
9   Y    IT    1.0
10  X    IT    1.0
11  Y    MV    2.0
```

As per above, we groupby 'group' and do a rolling count of the 'X's and 'Y's in column B with window length = 3. If 'X' is the current row, then we count the number of times 'X' appeared in the previous 3 observations within group 'group', not including the count of the current row (so shift back by period=1).

However, this code is slow and uses too much memory when using with large data sets. Grateful for an improvement on this.

Comment: interesting question. How many groups do you have, and how many unique values for 'B"?

Comment: I have about 30,000 groups but only a small number of unique values for B (around 10).

Comment: At `idx=0` there is no `X`  `IT` above it so `count=0` as . Next, at `idx=1` there does exist an `X` `IT` above it, so `count=1`. At `idx=2`, there is no `Y` `IT` above it, so `count=0`.  So on. At `idx=5`, there is one `Y` `MV` above it, so `count=1`. I got that. However, at `idx=6` there is no `X` `IT` above it in that window (`idx` `4` to `6`), so was expecting `count=0`. However, `count=2`. Why? Also below it. At `idx=11`, there is no `Y` `MT` above it in that window (`idx` `9` to `10`), was expecting a `count=0`. Then why `count=2`. I get: `[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

Comment: Its a rolling count of the 3 preceding values within the group. The previous 3 "IT" , excluding the current one, is Y X X. There are 2 X's. Hence 2

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what's the use-case / business meaning for this computation?

Comment: I wont dive into the specific use case. But more generally it may be interesting to know the number of times an individual ('group') performed a particular activity ('B') among other activities on offer, which could indicate interest in that activity, ability in that activity, restrictiveness to that activity, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I developed another solution to your question, which is based on group-by and the usage of one-hot encoding (`get_dummy`).

Here's the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['X', 'X' , 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'],
                   'group': ["IT", "IT", "IT", "MV", "MV", "MV", "IT", "MV", "MV", "IT", "IT", "MV"]})

# add a one-hot encoding to the dataframe. 
t = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df.B)], axis=1)

t.index.name = "inx"

# do a rolling sum of 4. It's the past 3, plus 1. 
t = t.groupby("group").rolling(4, min_periods = 1).sum()
t = t.reset_index().set_index("inx").sort_index()

# remove the extra '1' from the rolling result. 
t.loc[:, ["X", "Y"]] = t.loc[:, ["X", "Y"]] - 1

# merge back the results with the original dataframe. 
t = pd.concat([df, t[["X", "Y"]]], axis=1)

# create a 'count' column which is based on the values of 'B'. 
t["count"] = t.lookup(t.index, t.B )
```

The output is:

```
     B group    X    Y  count
inx                          
0    X    IT  0.0 -1.0    0.0
1    X    IT  1.0 -1.0    1.0
2    Y    IT  1.0  0.0    0.0
3    X    MV  0.0 -1.0    0.0
4    Y    MV  0.0  0.0    0.0
5    Y    MV  0.0  1.0    1.0
6    X    IT  2.0  0.0    2.0
7    X    MV  1.0  1.0    1.0
8    Y    MV  0.0  2.0    2.0
9    Y    IT  1.0  1.0    1.0
10   X    IT  1.0  1.0    1.0
11   Y    MV  0.0  2.0    2.0
```

---

All in one line:

```
df['count'] = (pd.concat([df, df['B'].str.get_dummies()], axis=1)
                 .groupby('group')
                 .rolling(4, min_periods=1)
                 .sum()
                 .sort_index(level=1)
                 .reset_index(drop=True)
                 .lookup(df.index, df['B']) - 1)
```

Comment: Did it help the memory use? I have a slightly better solution for the last step (replacing the contact), and doing it in a completely vectorized way.

Comment: Took the liberty of editing in my version of this answer developed independently, rather than post an answer repeating the same info. Hope that's alright.

Comment: Thanks this works great... It helps with memory use when we include only the 'group' column in the concat: `pd.concat([df['group'], pd.get_dummies(df['B'])]`. I use pd.get_dummies as 'B' can be integer